# jQuery - traversing continuously with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of tabs that activate different pages of content and I'd like them to loop automatically until the user clicks on one of them.

```
$("#projects_list ul li a").each(function() {
 activatetab($(this));
});
```

So I want `activatetab($(this))` to be executed every say 5000ms and once the final tab is activated it should start all over again. Can it be done this way? I can probably make a function like `activate_next_tab()` and then call it in `setInterval()` while tracking which tab was last activated and then finding the next one... but it's a bother. I want to do it this way.

Thanks

Comment: The solution you mentioned may not be *elegant*, but keep in mind it is still a solution. jQuery does not have timers or periodic executors built in. But there are plugins available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
var as = $("#projects_list ul li a"), i = 0, l = as.length;
setInterval(function(){
  activatetab($(as[i++ % l]))
}, 5000)
```

Some explanations:

- `as` is a jQuery object with the list of all `A` tags
- `i` is the counter
- `l` is the number of `A` tags
- the `setInterval` will repeat the function every 5000ms
- `i++` will increment the counter at every pass, and `% l` will insure that you never go over the number of `A` and "rotate"

Comment: thanks, but this just keeps activating the first element, it doesn't go to second, third, etc. I'm not sure what you did here so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly. I'm still not sure what you did but I'll decipher it when my head clears up. :)